# Android Studio - Lib Folder not showing up (libs/ lib)?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, libs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkMGO.png)

This is everything I am getting upon creating a flutter project. Please HELP!

I tried switching to "Project", look at the image and it shows all of the below. Nothing has changed. (I also don't have a "Android" option, just "Project" and a few others)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.